# The record you are attempting to load has a different type: noninventoryitem from the type specified: serviceitem

Tags: netsuite

I'm saving the vendor bill in NetSuite. and System give this error("The record you are attempting to load has a different type: noninventoryitem from the type specified: serviceitem.").
Can someone explain the what is the issue here and how I can fix this issue?

I have try to save many time but sysytem give same error and Im not able to save the bill from edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to customised scripts or workflows that apply to vendor bill which are for service item type only.

You can try goto Customisation > Scripted Record and then click view on Vendor Bill and see the list of scripts and workflows apply to bill.

Then try to disable one by one to find which one is causing the problem. Once you found the script/workflow that create the error, try to add a filter in the script/workflow to limit it to service item item type only.